# Gradle dependencies when compiled first time

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, dependencies

I am a newbie to gradle and other build tools. 
I am trying to write a piece of code to log some information using log4j.
So, I have to import the logger org.apache.log4j.* in my code. 
I also have a gradle file build.gradle within the project.
When I build the gradle file, I get a compilation error. I understand it will look for the above dependency while compiling. But according to my understanding gradle should download this from the repository.

Correct me if I am wrong. Help me to understand how this works in this scenario.

Comment: have you declared the according dependency and a repository in your build script?

Comment: Yes, This is a snippet of my build.gradle file
`code dependencies {<br>
     compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'   
} `

Answer (score 2):

Make your build.gradle like this:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8.1'
}
```

Add Main.java to folder src/main/java:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("started");
    }
}
```

And add log4j2.xml to src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Try to start main method.
If in your IDE you have some errors, try to update project. In Intellij IDEA for this you can use gradle->refresh project on the right side of the screen.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. 
Did I miss a dependency ? Was that the problem?

Comment: Nice to hear :) It's difficult to answer to your question without see full code :)

Comment: I am a newbie to gradle, I just was trying to understand how this build tool works. I just copied only your code (gradle, java and log4j) and did a refresh project.

Comment: You just add dependencies to build.gradle, refresh project in IDE (or start to build project) and after it gradle start to find all dependencies from all declared repositories and download it. In my example gradle find log4j dependencies in maven central repos, but it's possible to declare any another. 
Try to read more about gradle, there are a lot of documentation in official site.